# API access physics state

Tags: python, physics

Is there a way to access the full physics state from the API? E.g. the resulting forces/torques for a [constraint](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RigidBodyConstraint.html)?

It seems like only the body position transforms are available, but I'm also looking for velocities, accelerations, and force/torque. What is the best way to get at those values?